# Ocaml expression type confusion

Tags: function, tuples, ocaml

I wrote this ocaml function:

```
(* int Base.List.t -> Base.Int.t x Base.Int.t *)
let min_and_max lst =
  let mmax = ref Float.neg_infinity
  and mmin = ref Float.infinity in
    List.iter ~f:(fun v -> let fv = Float.of_int v in 
                  if fv > !mmax then mmax := fv
                  else if fv < mmin then mmin := fv)
              lst;
    (Int.of_float !mmin, Int.of_float !mmax)
```

It is supposed to return the min and max of a list of integers, but when I compile, I get this error:

```
File "02-exercises/24-refs/problem.ml", line 25, characters 21-23:
Error: This expression has type Base.Float.t = float
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

The error is pointing to the first `if` statement in that function. I must be making a very obvious mistake, but I can't see it.

---

#### Solution taking into account the answers and comments so far:

```
let min_and_max lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> failwith "Cannot find min and max of empty list"
  | v::[] -> (v,v)
  | a::b::rest -> 
    let mmax = ref (max a b)
    and mmin = ref (min a b) in
      List.iter ~f:(fun v -> 
                      if v > !mmax then mmax := v;
                      if v < !mmin then mmin := v)
                rest;
      (!mmin, !mmax)
```

Comment: Note that by converting to and from float like that, you lose precision. For example `min_and_max [115292150460684711]` would return `(115292150460684704, 115292150460684704)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how your compiler throws you that error. Your code contains several errors that it should detect before:

1. You make a wrong use of the label.
2. In the else arm, you are comparing against the ref `mmin` and not against its content —you missed the `!`—.
3. You confuse `int_of_float` function with `Int.of_float`, that don't exists.

In addition, the logical principle of the function isn't adequate. For example, the first value of the list will always enter in the `mmax` variable, because it will be greater than the negative infinity. But what if this value were the minimum?

Apart from the above, converting an integer to a float in this case is meaningless and causes precision loss and performance decrease. Nor is necessary to use refs.

This isn't a canonical way to proceed in a OCaml context. In OCaml it's important to try to find the simplest possible solution, because as soon as you start to complicate with the types, you end up being unable to solve the disaster.

I propose you a simpler solution for the problem, with the license to compose a polymorphic function, not only to integers:

```
let min_and_max lst =
    (List.fold_left (fun a b -> if a < b then a else b) (List.hd lst) lst),
    (List.fold_left (fun a b -> if a > b then a else b) (List.hd lst) lst);;
```

It's an elegant option and in addition it's based on terminal recursion. However, on that scheme you could redefine the functions yourself without using the predefined ones to go through the lists. You could also choose the two numbers with a single round, but it would be somewhat more complex to do.

Comment: Thanks for catching that error with not including `!` for getting the value of `mmin` I found it after going over the code again. I am solving the exercises found here: https://github.com/janestreet/learn-ocaml-workshop and this is problem 24 dealing with `refs` which is why I am using ref there. In addition, the compiler I am using is the one that came with the problem which I guess includes some utility libraries not commonly found in the regular ocaml compiler

Answer (score 2):

Base disables polymorphic comparison: you need to use a local open to compare floats with `>` or `<` : `Float.(fv > !mmax )`.

p.s.: The gratuitous conversion to float (and the use of references) is a bit strange and non-optimal.

Comment: Can you please explain what that syntax is. Is that a function call? What does it do differently from just doing a regular comparison?

Comment: This is a local open: it brings into the current scope all identifiers defined inside the module Float. And the module Base.Float defines its own `<` and `>` operators. Thus `Float.( x > y )` is equivalent to `Float.(>) x y` .